# how to increase nodejs default memory?

Tags: node.js

On Server startup exporting 2GB(Approximately) data from mongodb to redis,then getting error as `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`.

Then started server with this command `node --max-old-space-size=4076 server.js` and works fine. But needs to configure in nodejs applicaton so that node server always starts with 4gb memory. Please help me how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is there something that is stopping you from putting this in an npm start script?

Comment: Hi James, i am a newbie to nodejs. can you please tell me where exactly i need to keep this? can you provide sample code? i am very much grateful to you.

Comment: I posted an answer with some more details than I could have provided in a comment. Hope it helps you along.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 some-script.js
```

- Where *SomeScript* is the file name that you want to execute using
  node.

Comment: what is SomeScript.js here? where and what should I write there?

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati This is the script that you want to execute with the increased memory

Comment: The flag has to be first or it doesn't work. Should be `node --max-old-space-size=8192 SomeScript.js`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43758163/193896

Comment: FYI the number is KB, so 8192 = 8 GB. For more numbers [here](https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c).

Comment: strange argument name, is there an explanation for it?

Comment: @AlexanderMills The name refers to one of the bins of the (simple) generational garbage collector implemented in V8. In a nutshell, the (heap) memory is partitioned into sections dependent on the lifetime of the allocation units (JS objects) contained therein. 'old-space' is the section for, well, old units. See [An Introduction to V8 Garbage Collection](https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/12/08/nodejs-memory-limits-what-you-should-know.html#an-introduction-to-v8-garbage-collection) for more details

Answer (score 35):

one option: npm start scripts

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

These are added to your package.json under the "scripts" section

```
{
  //other package.json stuff

  "scripts":{
     "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4076 server.js"
  } 

}
```

then to run it call `npm start` instead of typing in node + args + execution point.

Note: if you name it something other than start, `npm run [yourScriptNameHere]` will be the command to run it

This is a better option than trying to reconfigure node to use 4gb by default (don't even know if its possible tbh).  It makes your configuration portable by using the baked in methods as it stands and allows others who encounter your code in the future to understand this is a need.

Comment: @InzamamMalik not that I know of - or could find on a quick google search.  I believe this is by design also.  The original post had a use case that could have been solved streaming data from one endpoint to the other and not buffering it all in memory.  Chances are if you need to override node (or really, v8) memory limits all the time, there's probably an architectural issue with your implementation.  If you still feel that you need it for every process, the start script really doesn't seem that inconvenient.

Comment: @InzamamMalik - you can do this globally on a system by saving the following environment variable - `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096`

Answer (score 29):

You can also set [`NODE_OPTIONS`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options) when running an npm script rather than `node` itself:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 serve",
},
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to resolve this, First way is to set memory size explicitly for your application, already answered above. And the other way is to set memory size globally for node - This is done by creating an **Environment variable**, with

```
variable name=NODE_OPTIONS
```

and

```
variable value=--max-old-space-size=4096
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the memory usage of the node globally, you can export environment variable, like this:

> export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

or 8GB:

> export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192