# node --max_old_space_size is not working

Tags: node.js, memory-management

Node Version: 6.9.x

My application was giving me `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

So I tried changing the memory allocation using `max_old_space_size` flag

While executing my server.js, I am giving the `--max_old_space_size=4096` argument.

However, it keeps crashing with same error as before. Also, I noticed the numbers in the error thrown while crashing. Looks like its still the default allocation of 1.4 GB.

Here's my error message:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   84567 ms: Mark-sweep 1375.1 (1401.9) -> 1374.7 (1402.9) MB, 88.7 / 0.4 ms (+ 0.8 ms in 3 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.5 ms) [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
   84648 ms: Mark-sweep 1374.7 (1402.9) -> 1374.7 (1402.9) MB, 81.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
   84734 ms: Mark-sweep 1374.7 (1402.9) -> 1374.3 (1401.9) MB, 86.0 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
   84825 ms: Mark-sweep 1374.3 (1401.9) -> 1374.0 (1400.9) MB, 90.9 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1bf641bcfb39 <JS Object>
    1: slowToString [buffer.js:460] [pc=0x2f7049a5d3d5] (this=0x93e46a2d6b1 <an Uint8Array with map 0x13be78e068d9>,encoding=0x1bf641bdd309 <String[4]: utf8>,start=53,end=3522765)
    2: toString [buffer.js:~488] [pc=0x2f70499b77a6] (this=0x93e46a2d6b1 <an Uint8Array with map 0x13be78e068d9>)
    3: arguments adaptor frame: 3->0
    4: deserialize [/opt/myServer/node_modu...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x10d2fbc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromOneByte(v8::internal::Vector<unsigned char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 8: v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int) [node]
 9: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding) [node]
10: node::Buffer::Utf8Slice(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [node]
11: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [node]
12: 0x9da914 [node]
13: 0x9daffe [node]
14: 0x2f7047a092a7
Aborted (core dumped)
```

In the "Last few GCs" section, the memory size mentioned is always around 1404 MB. What am I doing wrong?

Is the system not able to allocated it any more memory?

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you put the options before your script's filename:

- **Correct**: `node --max-old-space-size=10000 index.js`
- **Incorrect**: `node index.js --max-old-space-size=10000`

This one got me for a while.

Comment: It's always the stupid mistakes that we spend the most time on

Answer (score 11):

If you use newer version of NodeJs, you may not need this while it *should* use all available RAM. Yet people still hitting 2gb or similar memory limits.

**So here is the solution:**

You can add the flag for a single script but I found out that it doesn't always work. I usually use some CI tool that runs commands on the shell so for me it's ok to not have flag inside the package.json scripts section, it may be an option for you too. There are 2 more options. So all 3:

**Option 1. Set the flag to the single node script:**

`node --max-old-space-size=4076 /path/to/script.js`

**Option 2. Set env variable for single-shell:**

```sh
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4076"
node /path/to/script.js
```

**Option 3. Set env variable for this shell and all processes spawned by this shell:**

```sh
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4076"
node /path/to/script.js
```

> **Option #3** helped me many times when 1st didn't worked :)

Comment: yes for me also.Third solution is helped for me too

Comment: The third one is perfectly worked for me.

Comment: I'm on Windows 11 and needed to go the 3rd option route (64-bit Node 11.9.0).

Comment: More details...

My "npm run build" command executes webpack 4.29.6 with terser-webpack-plugin 1.2.3. Memory usage explodes during "chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin" (after adding a lot of new TypeScript code). Probably webpack runs in separate cmd shell and wasn't picking up max-old-space-size passed in when running the script or set in the calling cmd environment.

Comment: @cchapin i think you right why only #3 is working. Webpack probably spawns multiple child processes and one of them may go out of memory and probably webpack itself is not using that much but those children are. Though it's speculation, if someone know exact reason, please share.

Comment: option 3 worked for me on a mac. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Now this flag is useless:

> Versions of Node that are >= 12 should not need to use the
> --optimize_for_size and --max_old_space_size flags because JavaScript heap limit will be based on available memory.

Comment: Can you please link to source?

Comment: Sure, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-memory-use#tuning-the-garbage-collector

Comment: This is not accurate, they increased the default max size, but not enough to run typescript or other memory pigs that need 4GB+ of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have been using 64-bit NodeJS. I have a similar problem and after all I found out my problem was related to NodeJS itself. the 32-bit version of NodeJS can only give you up to 2GB of space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you think it is not clear?

Comment: Thank-you ! You saved me a lot of time 
A developper in the team had memory errors and he had 32bits version installed. After installing 64bits version all is working fine !

Comment: @FlorianBezagu It makes me happy that I was able to help someone.

Answer (score 2):

setting
`export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=16384"`
before running a npm command will work

Answer (score 0):

Try using --max-old-space-size=4096, if it does not work see if you have free memory to allocate 4gb.

Comment: do you mean `--max_old_space_size` ? because look at the question, I've already done that. and I have tried `2048` as well, and I definitely had that much free

Comment: Ok, I thought i was a typo. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: [Dashes and underscores both work](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10137#issuecomment-294352457)

Comment: Someties it doesn't for some reason https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2738#issuecomment-294354111

Answer (score 0):

if  you are using express generator then in package.json update script

```
scripts": {

   "start" :"node --max-old-space-size=4076 ./bin/www"

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

the solution in my case was related with the html.
i was using Vue 2 and on my html template i used dynamic data on a if statement:

```
<div>
  {{variableOne
    ?variableOne
    :variableTwo}}
  </div>
```

so my error was that it seems that you can not write a if statement in more that one line inside the brackets, so i fixed it just writing the code in one line:

```
<div>
  {{variableOne?variableOne:variableTwo}}
  </div>
```