# How to increase Javascript heap size for Ionic

Tags: node.js, build, out-of-memory, ionic3, heap-memory

I am having an *out of memory* problem with running a build of an Ionic application with `--release` and `--prod` flag. Unfortunately, as it seams, the space of memory that Node is allowed to use is not sufficient for the process and it's producing the following error (probably after no memory blocks are available to carry out the operation):

[image]

As suggested in [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34358130/4373584) answer, I tried to exploit the `max_old_space_size` flag from the `package.json` `start` script before the build command to no avail. Mainly because the node process is run internally by the Ionic CLI way after the flag is set.

I also tried to re-install Ionic with a bigger heap size *as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939496/4373584) answer*, but that seems to only address memory limitations during installation of the Ionic package itself, and not any subsequent operations with Ionic via the CLI.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

#### Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (D:\ionic\<...>\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
Gulp CLI    : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.5.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.2
Node              : v6.10.2
npm               : 4.0.5
OS                : Windows 7
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution was to increase the memory size for Javascript heap internally (*from Ionic's point of view*) as and when the Ionic CLI kicks the process.

The [post on Github by @timothybclayton on a similar issue under ionic-app-scripts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/64) helped me figure this out.

However, I had to do it in quite different way than that because I had **Nodist** as package manager for NodeJS. So, I had to go to the `/bin` folder under Nodist installation directory and tweak the `ionic.cmd` file.

This is how the `ionic.cmd` file looks as it has now allows plenty of memory for NodeJS to carry out the process:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=12288 "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=12288 "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
)
```

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue, not only for Ionic, but for any other memory-intensive process with NodeJS.

Comment: --max_old_space_size=12288, what is "12288" for? I try this but still error

Comment: `12288` is the RAM size in MB on my PC that I allotted to Ionic - which is 12GB. Yours depends on the amount of RAM in your machine - e.g. if you have 8GBs of RAM, you can assign any amount `less than or equal to 1024 * 8` to the flag.

Comment: Is there any solution for Ubuntu/Linux/MAC??

Comment: If you're using `nvm`, search for any equivalent file for `ionic.cmd` in the bin directory.

Comment: A user on a thread on github suggests something like the following by setting the flag on an alias for npm: 

`alias npm='node --max_old_space_size=8000 /usr/bin/npm'`.
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238

Answer (score 0):

I flagged this as a duplicate, but in case anyone happens across it before it is consolidated, I posted the modern solution to this problem over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895989/4200039:

> As of v8.0 shipped August 2017, the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable exposes this configuration (see NODE_OPTIONS has landed in 8.x!). Per the article, only options whitelisted in the source are permitted, which includes "--max_old_space_size".
>
> So I put in my .bashrc:
> export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096